# Хэширование алгоритмом CRC

Tags: java, хеширование, crc

Объясните как работает этот алгоритм ибо хорошей, понятной информации по этому алгоритму я не нашел. Все описывают в математических формулах, а я хочу понять саму суть алгоритма. То как он работает, а в частности, что он он делает с поступившими данными.

Comment: CRC это общее название для семейства алгоритмов. а каком конкретно вы спрашиваете?

Comment: В его основе деление на полином. Там не может не быть математики.

Comment: CRC не является хэшом, насколько я знаю...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача crc очень проста - в соответствии с поступившими байтами поставить им в соответствие 4 байта (или 2, crc бывают разные). При этом выполняются следующие условия:

- у одинаковых входных данных будет одинаковый crc.
- у разных входных данных будет разный crc, но может быть и одинаковый.
- у входных данных, которые отличаются совсем немножко (несколько бит), скорее всего будут разные crc.

Само вычисление описано в википедии и в конце концов сводится к математическим формулам. Но если отбросить все это, то в сухом остатке остается в основном [xor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2) и сдвиг. То есть, с входного потока читаем данные, сдвигаем/ксорим.

Возьмем в [википедии](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) очень простой crc8 и разберем

```
/*
  Name  : CRC-8
  Poly  : 0x31    x^8 + x^5 + x^4 + 1 - над его выбором сидят математики и криптоаналитики
  Init  : 0xFF над этим также
  Revert: false
  XorOut: 0x00
  Check : 0xF7 ("123456789") контрольное значение, что бы проверить реализацию
  MaxLen: 15 байт(127 бит) - обнаружение
    одинарных, двойных, тройных и всех нечетных ошибок
*/
unsigned char Crc8(unsigned char *pcBlock, unsigned int len)
{
    // начальное значение. Выбирается с потолка или экспериментально
    unsigned char crc = 0xFF; 
    unsigned int i;

    while (len--) // пока у нас есть данные
    {
        crc ^= *pcBlock++; // ксорим очередной байт

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
            // применяем полином. тут просто ксорим и/или сдвигаем.
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x31 : crc << 1;
    }

    return crc;
}
```

В принципе, если полином пуст, то результат это просто последовательно проксоренные байты (для crc8) или int'ы (для crc32).

В [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) описаны разлиные значения полиномов и начальных значний (все те магические константы) для различных модификаций алгорима. Какое выбрать - это сложная задача, тут математики пусть сидят и думают. Для своих приложений главное, чтобы с двух сторон был один и тот же алгоритм.